# Алгоритм Дейкстры. Почему все веса должны быть больше, либо равны нулю?

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Сидел, читал про алгоритм Дейкстры и Форда-Беллмана. В определении данных алгоритмов есть условие - всё веса рёбер должны быть больше, либо равны нулю. Объяснения не нашел. Почему накладывается такое условие?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

На самом деле все по-другому.

Алгоритм Дейкстры является в некотором роде "жадным" - найдя один раз минимальный путь до вершины, он фиксирует его как минимальный навсегда - поскольку путь через другие вершины не может быть короче найденного.

Но в графе с отрицательными дугами это не так! Рассмотрим такой вот граф, заданный матрицей смежности:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   | А | Б | В |
+---+---+---+---+
| А |   | 4 | 2 |
+---+---+---+---+
| Б |   |   |-3 |
+---+---+---+---+
| В |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Запустим алгоритм Дейкстры из вершины **А**. На первом шаге у нас будут расстояния до вершин **Б** и **В** - 4 и 2 соответственно, поэтому алгоритм решит, что уже нашел кратчайший путь к вершине **В** - ведь кратчайший путь к **В** никак не может идти через **Б**, не так ли? С сожалению, не так - очевидно, путь **А-Б-В** на самом деле короче чем **А-В**.

Поэтому алгоритм Дейкстры не может работать при наличии в графе отрицательных дуг.

Алгоритм же Форда-Беллмана (он же алгоритм Беллмана-Форда) таких предположений не делает - а потому может работать почти на любых графах, ценой значительного замедления по сравнению с Дейкстрой. Почему я говорю "почти на любых"? Потому что алгоритм Форда-Беллмана все равно не может работать *на графах с отрицательными циклами.*

Просто потому что понятие "кратчайший путь" в таких графах не определено. Всегда можно пройтись по отрицательному циклу еще один раз - и получить еще более короткий путь.

Тем не менее, существует *модификация* алгоритма Беллмана-Форда, которая позволяет обнаружить цикл отрицательного веса в графе. Достаточно ограничить количество итераций количеством вершин в графе - после чего сделать еще одну итерацию. До вершин, веса которых обновились на последней итерации, не существует кратчайшего пути из-за цикла.

Ну и последнее. Если рассматривать неориентированный граф - то надо помнить, что в нем любое ребро отрицательного веса автоматически создает цикл отрицательного веса из двух вершин.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь всё стало на свои места)

Answer (score -2):

А вообще я так прикинул, пусть есть отрицательные веса. Найдем ребро e с наименьшим весом (то есть ребро с отрицательным весом максимального модуля). тогда w(e) = -n, где n > 0. Сместим все веса на n. Запускаем алгоритм (он теперь отработает на корректных данных) и вычитаем сколько "лишнего накручено". Или бред написал?)

Comment: Вроде бы Дейкстра работает для графов с ребрами отрицательных весов, но не для всех. Не уверен, вот и спросил)

Comment: мысль хорошая, но тогда цена пути будет зависеть не только от оригинальной цены ребер, но и от их количества. т.е. до операции стоимость двух путей может быть равна, например, 10+10=20 и -10+10+20 = 20. а после коррекции +10 -  уже 20+20=40 и 0+20+30=50. и путь, например, 1+1+1+1+1+1 станет уже не кратчайшим.

Comment: Достаточно интересно получается. Но не знаю, будет ли это работать на всех графах.